# Call SLIM rest endpoint for internal consumption

Tags: php, api, curl, slim

Been stuck with this seemingly basic problem since a long time now.
I have the following Slim framework folder structure in my web app.

```
/
- api/
      Slim/
      index.php
- js/
- css/
- index.php
```

In api/index.php, I have methods defined like :

```
$app->get('/topRatedCities/:cityid/','getTopRatedCitiess');
```

Now typically I use the api by calling it from outside my web app (from mobile app):
http://domain.com/api/topRatedCities/4

The problem is,

I want to call the API functions from inside my web app without generating a new external HTTP request like above. 
When I try to do this using cURL:

http://127.0.0.1/api/topRatedCities/4

It reroutes to the domain name which is of no use for me.
Is there any function from where I can directly call slimframework and the response from outside the Slim framework folder?

This is the .htaccess inside the api folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /api

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30979788/1992780) could help you.